# Oracle Enterprise Monitor behind nginx proxy keep redirecting infinitely

Tags: nginx, nginx-reverse-proxy, oracle-enterprise-manager

I am trying to setup OEM behind nginx reverse proxy. Here is my nginx config.

```
 location ~* "^/em/(.*)" {

            add_header X-debug-message "Just for testing" always;

            proxy_redirect https://em/ https://local.mydomain.com:8080/em/;
            rewrite ^/em/em/(.*) ^/em/$1 break;
            proxy_cookie_path ~^(.+)$ "/em; domain=.mydomain.com";

            proxy_pass https://em/em/$1;

        }
```

Here are the request and response data for first 4 pages after which it keeps redirecting last page in a loop.

```
Request URL: https://local.mydomain.com:8080/em/
Request Method: GET
Status Code: 302 Moved Temporarily
Remote Address: 192.168.56.102:8080
Referrer Policy: no-referrer-when-downgrade
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Language: en
Content-Type: text/plain
Date: Thu, 19 Dec 2019 14:48:23 GMT
Location: https://local.mydomain.com:8080/em/em/login.jsp
Server: nginx/1.15.8
Set-Cookie: ORA_SMP_EM_AUTH_27122419296023168200=YFEeoZWcMPfA8gQQ82F0czCIcgA5rumW3-u1gJZ8DZ0W8Zr6Uxpa!371330538; path=/em; domain=.mydomain.com; secure; HttpOnly
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
X-debug-message: Just for testing
X-ORCL-EMOA: true
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.9,pa;q=0.8
Cache-Control: no-cache
Connection: keep-alive
Cookie: ORA_SMP_EM_AUTH_27122419296023168200=ZY0aWFKYSHRDLT5NpsYrDVJ6lnMQbzAR5LGitj2FDX5zJExGpuFi!371330538; __cfduid=d490c5ed0fba5408abb5ffebaf9e1ad561548864527; _ga=GA1.2.147384809.1548864525
Host: local.mydomain.com:8080
Pragma: no-cache
Sec-Fetch-Mode: navigate
Sec-Fetch-Site: none
Sec-Fetch-User: ?1
Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/79.0.3945.79 Safari/537.36
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Request URL: https://local.mydomain.com:8080/em/em/login.jsp
Request Method: GET
Status Code: 302 Moved Temporarily
Remote Address: 192.168.56.102:8080
Referrer Policy: no-referrer-when-downgrade
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Language: en
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
Date: Thu, 19 Dec 2019 14:48:24 GMT
Location: https://local.mydomain.com:8080/em/em/faces/logon/core-uifwk-console-login
Server: nginx/1.15.8
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
X-debug-message: Just for testing
X-ORACLE-DMS-ECID: 005aWybD0OcE8T0_zxDCiW0001L^000NGP
X-ORCL-EMOA: true
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.9,pa;q=0.8
Cache-Control: no-cache
Connection: keep-alive
Cookie: ORA_SMP_EM_AUTH_27122419296023168200=YFEeoZWcMPfA8gQQ82F0czCIcgA5rumW3-u1gJZ8DZ0W8Zr6Uxpa!371330538; __cfduid=d490c5ed0fba5408abb5ffebaf9e1ad561548864527; _ga=GA1.2.147384809.1548864525
Host: local.mydomain.com:8080
Pragma: no-cache
Sec-Fetch-Mode: navigate
Sec-Fetch-Site: none
Sec-Fetch-User: ?1
Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/79.0.3945.79 Safari/537.36
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Request URL: https://local.mydomain.com:8080/em/em/faces/logon/core-uifwk-console-login
Request Method: GET
Status Code: 200 OK
Remote Address: 192.168.56.102:8080
Referrer Policy: no-referrer-when-downgrade
Cache-Control: no-cache
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Encoding: gzip
Content-Language: en
Content-Type: text/html;charset=utf-8
Date: Thu, 19 Dec 2019 14:48:24 GMT
Expires: Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 GMT
Server: nginx/1.15.8
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Vary: Accept-Encoding
X-debug-message: Just for testing
X-ORACLE-DMS-ECID: 005aWybE49ZE8T0_zxDCiW0001L^000Ma1
X-ORCL-EMOA: true
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.9,pa;q=0.8
Cache-Control: no-cache
Connection: keep-alive
Cookie: ORA_SMP_EM_AUTH_27122419296023168200=YFEeoZWcMPfA8gQQ82F0czCIcgA5rumW3-u1gJZ8DZ0W8Zr6Uxpa!371330538; __cfduid=d490c5ed0fba5408abb5ffebaf9e1ad561548864527; _ga=GA1.2.147384809.1548864525
Host: local.mydomain.com:8080
Pragma: no-cache
Sec-Fetch-Mode: navigate
Sec-Fetch-Site: none
Sec-Fetch-User: ?1
Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/79.0.3945.79 Safari/537.36
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Request URL: https://local.mydomain.com:8080/em/em/faces/logon/core-uifwk-console-login?_afrLoop=5008527327684549&_afrWindowMode=2&Adf-Window-Id=w0
Request Method: GET
Status Code: 200 OK
Remote Address: 192.168.56.102:8080
Referrer Policy: no-referrer-when-downgrade
Cache-Control: no-cache
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Encoding: gzip
Content-Language: en
Content-Type: text/html;charset=utf-8
Date: Thu, 19 Dec 2019 14:48:24 GMT
Expires: Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 GMT
Server: nginx/1.15.8
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Vary: Accept-Encoding
X-debug-message: Just for testing
X-ORACLE-DMS-ECID: 005aWybFUTEE8T0_zxDCiW0001L^000Ma2
X-ORCL-EMOA: true
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.9,pa;q=0.8
Cache-Control: no-cache
Connection: keep-alive
Cookie: ORA_SMP_EM_AUTH_27122419296023168200=YFEeoZWcMPfA8gQQ82F0czCIcgA5rumW3-u1gJZ8DZ0W8Zr6Uxpa!371330538; __cfduid=d490c5ed0fba5408abb5ffebaf9e1ad561548864527; _ga=GA1.2.147384809.1548864525
Host: local.mydomain.com:8080
Pragma: no-cache
Referer: https://local.mydomain.com:8080/em/em/faces/logon/core-uifwk-console-login
Sec-Fetch-Mode: navigate
Sec-Fetch-Site: same-origin
Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/79.0.3945.79 Safari/537.36
_afrLoop: 5008527327684549
_afrWindowMode: 2
Adf-Window-Id: w0
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

When I am calling the page directly without nginx reverse proxy, it works and use similar headers. I am using https connection for nginx.

Comment: Your use of `$1` is ambiguous. You should use a named capture in the `location` regex.

Comment: @RichardSmith, thank you. I will make this change. But it still doesn't solve the issue I am facing.